# Configuring Hyperion Shared Services

Tags: oracle, obiee, hyperion

We have configured Oracle Hyperion Essbase with OBIEE on 9704 port. Now , we need to implement security using shared services rather than using weblogic.How can we proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually install Stand Alone Essbase and Foundation suite, the version you just install is quite different for the security administration. You will also need to reconfigure your environment